# Restart wifi interface from a python script completely independentely

Tags: python, linux, wifi

I am restarting wifi interface like this:

```
interface = 'wlan0'
proc = subprocess.Popen(['ifdown {}'.format(interface)], shell=True)
proc.communicate()
proc.wait()
time.sleep(1)
proc = subprocess.Popen(['ifup {}'.format(interface)], shell=True)
proc.communicate()
proc.wait()
```

After the successful connection, I am seeing the wpa_supplicant & dhclient process like this:

```
root     19627     1  0 02:22 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/python3 /opt/awaregui/bin/app.py >>/var/log/awaregui_error.log
root     19628 19627 57 02:22 ?        00:00:16 /usr/bin/python3 /opt/awaregui/bin/app.py
root     19791     2  0 02:22 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:1]
root     19833     1  0 02:22 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -s -B -P /run/wpa_supplicant.wlan0.pid -i wlan0 -D nl80211,wext -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
root     19855     2  0 02:23 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u8:2]
root     19859     2  0 02:23 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/3:1]
root     19961     1  0 02:23 ?        00:00:00 dhclient -v -pf /run/dhclient.wlan0.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.wlan0.leases wlan0
```

(The process id is 19833 and 19961)

The problem is, if I stop parent python script, both of **wpa_supplicant** & **dhclient** are killed as well.
Thus, wifi interface got dropped.

Is there any way of calling `ifdown wlan0` and `ifup wlan0` pretty independently?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just talking about WiFi and if you have configured your wireless config files properly,

you can also use 
`wifi down; wifi`

Also, you can use os.system package to run terminal command.